# Visual Studio Setup exe version different from Properties version

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project

I have created a Visual Studio Setup project and have set the version to 1.1.5.  When I build my setup project the setup.exe file version is 9.0.21022.8.  How would I retrieve the 1.1.5 file version from my setup project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this through the a blog entry series from b#
http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/06/06/linq-to-msi-part-0-introduction.aspx

Comment: that answer is down :(

Answer (score 0):

`setup.exe` is just a bootstrapper that eventually launches your MSI.

The same executable is used with every MSI that you build, so its version isn't related to the deployment project that it is associated with; the version of your application is **inside of the MSI file**.

[**Programatically reading MSI build version**](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Installation/MSI/Q_23134637.html) may be useful to you, it uses [`WindowsInstaller.Installer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369432(VS.85).aspx) to get the MSI version.

Comment: You are correct.  The exe just looks for prereqs and then launches the msi.  I can not view the solution from EE.  I usually can, wierd.